# Why does this code generate the error "The end tag "</c:when" is unbalanced"?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I don't understand why I get the error:

```
The end tag "</c:when" is unbalanced
```

when this code is run:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${label == 'Apple'}">
        <form:form modelAttribute="fruit" action="/fruit/${fruitId}" method="post">                 
        <form:input path="fruitId" type="hidden" value="${fruitId}"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${label == 'Orange'}">
        <form:form modelAttribute="fruit" action="/fruit/${fruitId}" method="post">
        <form:input path="fruitId" type="hidden" value="${fruitId}"/>
    </c:when>               
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an unclosed `<form:form>` tag.

Comment: But I can't close the form tag until later in the JSP. I need this check here. Is there no way to have this here?

Comment: Then open the form earlier.  If you truly need split forms, you could use JavaScript to populate the values from one into another as necessary.

Comment: @Brian Why do you need that check there? Both paths are the same. In any case, you can't randomly interweave tags like that--think of it like XML or HTML.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I found that issue was using html comment syntax to comment out JSTL codes. Therefore recheck your html file which contains JSTL syntax to check you have done the same mistake. **Please refer below example:**

```
<!-- <security:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ASSOC_COMPANY','PUBLIC_COMPANY', 'INDIVIDUAL')"> -->
```

change above comment to below comment.

```
<%-- <security:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ASSOC_COMPANY','PUBLIC_COMPANY', 'INDIVIDUAL')"> --%>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I forgot to close a JSTL tag.

This is where should I fix

```
<c:set var="attendance" value="${hallManager.selectAttandanceRegisterByAttID()}" >
```

And after I changed to this it's fine.

```
<c:set var="attendance" value="${hallManager.selectAttandanceRegisterByAttID()}" />
```

or

```
<c:set var="attendance" value="${hallManager.selectAttandanceRegisterByAttID()}" ></c:set>
```

Some tricks to fix this problem quickly:
If you have IDEs like Netbeans, please try 
1.Collapse all tags and expand one by one to see which one you did not close.
2. Type " and look at the popup menu(if you have enabled it). If there is any unclosed tag it will show up.